# Jquery selector for all elements with class in a form that are after one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I need to find all elements with class `'complexList'` in form that are after `'el'`.

**Example**

```
var el = $(this);
var els = $('#' + obj.tableId + '_editorForm').find('.complexList');
el.nextAll('.complexList') //dont work
```

Thanks

Comment: Show your html please.

Comment: do you mean any comlexList that comes after a single el or do you mean any complexList that immediately follows an el?

Answer (score 1):

If `nextAll` doesn't work, it means there are elements at various levels of nesting. But you can still do it, with [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) and [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice).

```
els = els.slice(els.index(el) + 1);
```

`index`, when called as above, finds the index of the given element in the matched set; `slice` returns a subset of elements from a set. So we ask for the subset starting with the element after `el`.

Example:

```js
var obj = {
  tableId: "foo"
};
$(document.body).on("click", ".complexList", function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var els = $('#' + obj.tableId + '_editorForm').find('.complexList');
  els.css("color", ""); // clear previous
  els = els.slice(els.index(el) + 1);
  els.css("color", "blue");
});
```

```html
All of the text fields below are `.complexList` fields. Click any of them to turn all `.complexList` elements <em>after</em> it blue.
<form id="foo_editorForm">
  <label>
    Field 1:
    <input type="text" class="complexList" value="field1">
  </label>
  <label>
    Field 2:
    <input type="text" class="complexList" value="field2">
  </label>
  <label>
    Field 3:
    <input type="text" class="complexList" value="field3">
  </label>
  <label>
    Field 4:
    <input type="text" class="complexList" value="field4">
  </label>
  <label>
    Field 5:
    <input type="text" class="complexList" value="field4">
  </label>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```